# Normalize light fall off

Tags: texturing, light, lighting, photogrammetry

I want to 3D scan an object, take pictures, determine the camera positions (using f-spy) and then texture paint (in stencil mode) the textures onto the object. Of course, the images taken have vignetting of the camera, and of course the lighting in the area is not homogenous.

I am wondering if there is a (feasible) way to normalize the light, so the textures on the object do not have the 'baked' lighting of the original images taking. (Taken into account the vignetting was normalized already).

Maybe it is possible in such way to put a known object in a room, photograph it,  apply 3d photogrammetry and from there calculate the position of different light sources/influences?

Comment: I don't think you will achieve good results with projection painting, unless 1) the material is diffuse and 2) you change the lighting direction between shots, so you can mask areas in the shadow. Since 2) is bad for 3D reconstruction this wouldn't be a good approach. Removing lighting is a topic of research, however the estimation is difficult because it depends on the material properties, e.g. glossy materials behave different in light than diffuse ones. Professional photogrammetry software include features for lighting removal which work for simpler cases.